# Monitoring Wireless modem without wired network

Tags: monitoring

I have a **wireless modem** in home and home devices are **not** wired.

Is it possible to find out how much is traffic is sent/received by each device? (preferably based on `MAC ID`)

Answer (score 0):

under WIFI to know the bandwith used by any device connected.. it is tricky..
1 best solution..  in your wifi router you can control this since every package goes through it.. I will install openWRT etc to be able to use Linux tools. maybe your router already has this capability.
2. dirty from a regular device.. MITM attack and start monitoring a single devide... example bmon tool pointing at the virtual interface.